# I want to do 2d array interpolation for interger preserved for image creating

Tags: python, interpolation

I want to perform 2D array's integer-conserved interpolation.

I have wafer data from wm-811k that contains many arrays of wafer picture.

One of the arrays is this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfwx9.png)

> array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0,
> 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
> [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
> [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
> [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
> [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0],
> [0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0],
> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
> [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0],
> [2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2],
> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
> [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
> [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
> [2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1],
> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
> [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
> [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
> [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
> [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
> [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2,
> 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

This is 26x26 2D image.

But I want to make this 64x64 2D array that preserves original image.
So the final array have to consist of integer [0,1,2] same as original array.

I think this is not that easy because it is not common multiple with 26 and 64, so maybe I need some interpolation.

I think the whole process would be like this :

1. Change the array as image file(jpg, png)
2. Resizing as 64x64 pixel image with interpolation
3. Recognizing the image and convert the color into [0,1,2]

But, I started python one weeks ago, so I have no idea how to perform these whole process...

Please give me another better methods or the ways to perform these process...